# How to show a modal popup on submission of another modal

Tags: scala, reactjs

I have done a one modal popup in react but I need to show another modal on submission of first modal. And I need to know how the backend works with modal?

```
val component = ReactComponentB[Props]("AddNewAgent")
    .initialState(State()) // initial state from TodoStore 
    .backend(new AddNewAgent.Backend(_))
    .renderPS(($, P, S) => { 
       val B = $.backend
       Button(
        Button.Props(
          B.addNewAgentForm(),
          CommonStyle.default,
          Seq(DashBoardCSS.Style.backgroundTransperant)),
          <.img(HeaderCSS.Style.imgLogo, ^.src := "./assets/images/profile.jpg"),
          if(S.showNewAgentForm)
            AddNewAgentForm(AddNewAgentForm.Props(B.addNewAgent))
          else 
            Seq.empty[ReactElement]) 
       })
   .configure(OnUnmount.install)
   .build
```

I am referring to this [scalajs-spa-tutorial](http://ochrons.github.io/scalajs-spa-tutorial)

Comment: Please provide some code and scenario

Comment: val component = ReactComponentB[Props]("AddNewAgent")
    .initialState(State()) // initial state from TodoStore
    .backend(new AddNewAgent.Backend(_))
    .renderPS(($, P, S) => {
      val B = $.backend
         Button(Button.Props(B.addNewAgentForm(), CommonStyle.default, Seq(DashBoardCSS.Style.backgroundTransperant)),<.img(HeaderCSS.Style.imgLogo, ^.src := "./assets/images/profile.jpg"),
           if (S.showNewAgentForm) AddNewAgentForm(AddNewAgentForm.Props(B.addNewAgent))
         else
           Seq.empty[ReactElement])
    })
    .configure(OnUnmount.install)
    .build